# Rotated Element Overflow

Tags: html, css, transform

For some reason, my rotated element isn't obeying the overflow rule? How can I keep my rotated division contained in the parent division?

Thanks for all your help in advance.

```
#box{
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

.full-width{
    width: 100%;
    height: 900px;
}

#pull-out{
    width:1800px;
    height: 1800px;
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    background: #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    right: -1273px;
    top: -450px;
}


<div id="box" class="full-width" style="background-image: url(images/5.jpg)">
    <div id="pull-out"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with the positioning of the inside div. You need to make it relative to the full-width div by setting

```
position:relative;
```

on the .full-width div.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s8n88gce/1/